# Changing toolbar item from toolbar subclass does not update toolbar immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitoolbar

I have a subclass of `UIToolbar`. I created it because I have the same toolbar on multiple pages(`UIViewControllers`). I took `UIToolbar` on my `UIViewControllers` (I am using storyboards) and assign this subclass to the `UIToolbar` class.

Also each item on that toolbar is created with a custom view (`UIButton`). When I change one of the items from its subclass, it's not reflecting immediately on the toolbar. I have to go to another screen and come back to view the updated result.

Is there any way to update immediately? Thanks.

Comment: Why did you subclass your `UIToolbar`? If only for cosmetic concerns, you did it wrong.